# Drupal 7 Form Invalid foreach with tableselect EDIT - How to delete selected rows from tableselect

Tags: api, drupal-7, form-api

What I am trying to do is create a selectlist using the form API, where a user can select rows and press a delete button that deletes the selected rows from the database and reloads the table with a conformation that those selected had been deleted. With my current code, when I hit the delete button I get this error:

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in form_execute_handlers() (line 1431 of C:\xampp\htdocs\amaware\includes\form.inc).

Here is the code:

```
            /**
             * Implements hook_menu().
             */
            function smsfeed_menu() {
              $items = array();

              $items['admin/config/content/smsfeed'] = array(
                'title' => 'SMS Messages and Newsletters',
                'description' => 'Edit the Setting for the SMS Feed and Newsletter',
                'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
                'page arguments' => array('smsfeed_form'),
                'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
                'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
                );

              $items['admin/config/content/smsfeed/settings'] = array(
                'title' => 'Settings',
                'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
                    'weight' => 1,
                );  

              $items['admin/config/content/smsfeed/newsletter'] = array(
                'title' => 'Newsletter',
                'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
                    'page arguments' => array('newsletter_table_form'),
                'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
                'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
                    'weigth' => 2,
                    );

              $items['admin/config/content/smsfeed/feed'] = array(
                'title' => 'SMS Feed',
                'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
                'page arguments' => array('feed_form'),
                'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
                'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
                    'weight' => 3,
                    );

              $items['admin/config/content/smsfeed/questions'] = array(
                'title' => 'Questions',
                'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
                'page arguments' => array('questions_form'),
                'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
                'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
                    'weigth' => 4,
                    );

              return $items;
            }

            /**
             * Page callback: SMS Settings
             *
             * @see smsfeed_menu()
             */
            function smsfeed_form($form, &$form_state) {
              $form['response_time'] = array(
                '#type' => 'textfield',
                '#title' => t('Response Time (In Days)'),
                '#default_value' => variable_get('response_time', 3),
                '#size' => 2,
                '#maxlength' => 2,
                '#description' => t('The response time, in days, that users should expect.'),
              );

                $form['feed_keyword'] = array(
                  '#type' => 'textfield',
                '#title' => t('Feed Keyword'),
                '#default_value' => variable_get('feed_keyword', 'FEED'),
                '#size' => 10,
                '#maxlength' => 10,
                '#description' => t('The keyword users should text to have their message moderated and added to the website feed.'),
              );

                $form['join_keyword'] = array(
                  '#type' => 'textfield',
                '#title' => t('Join Keyword'),
                '#default_value' => variable_get('join_keyword', 'JOIN'),
                '#size' => 10,
                '#maxlength' => 10,
                '#description' => t('The keyword users should text to be added to the newsletter list.'),
              );

                $form['quit_keyword'] = array(
                  '#type' => 'textfield',
                '#title' => t('Quite Keyword'),
                '#default_value' => variable_get('quit_keyword', 'QUIT'),
                '#size' => 10,
                '#maxlength' => 10,
                '#description' => t('The keyword users should text to be removed from the newsletter list.'),
              );    

              return system_settings_form($form);
            }

            /**
             * Page Callback Newsletter
             */

            function newsletter_table_form($form, $form_state) {
                $rows = array();
                $header = array(t('User Name'), t('User Number'), t('User E-mail'),);

                $query = db_select('sms_newsletter');
                $query->fields('sms_newsletter', array('name', 'number', 'email',))
                    ->orderBy('name', 'ASC');
                $results = $query->execute();

                foreach ($results as $line) {
                    $rows[] = array(
                        $line->name,
                        $line->number,
                        $line->email,
                    );
                }

              $form['table'] = array(
                '#type' => 'tableselect',
                '#header' => $header,
                '#options' => $rows,
                '#empty' => t('No users found'),
              );

              $form['delete'] = array(
                '#type' => 'submit',
                '#value' => t('Delect Selected'),
                    '#submit' => 'newsletter_table_form_delete'
              );
              return $form;
            }

            function newsletter_table_form_delete ($form, &$form_state) {
                foreach ($form_state['values']['collections'] as $key => $value) {
                    if ($value) {
                            $delete = db_delete('sms_newsletter')
                            -> execute();
                    }
                }   
            }
```

Any help is deeply appreciated.

EDIT:
I've edited my news_letter_table_form to read:

```
function newsletter_table_form_delete ($form, $form_state) {
    foreach (($form_state['values']['table']) as $rows) {
            //$delete = db_delete('sms_newsletter')
            //-> execute();
            drupal_set_message ('' . $rows  . '');
    //drupal_set_message ('' . $form_state['values']['table']       . '');
    }
}
```

And the new output leaves me puzzled as to how I'd identify selected rows, and delete them from the database. Using the above newsletter_table_form_delete I get the following output:

1. If I select the top row nothing happens
2. If I select the second row the output is 1
3. If I select the third row the output is 2 and so on
4. If I select multiple rows the output is an unordered html list of the selected rows.

I'm curious now how I could take what I have now and change it so I can delete selected rows from the database.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing

```
  $form['delete'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Delect Selected'),
        '#submit' => 'newsletter_table_form_delete'
  );
```

to

```
  $form['delete'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Delect Selected'),
        '#submit' => array('newsletter_table_form_delete') // <-- make this an array
  );
```

Based on the additional info added in your question edit, I noticed that your tableselect is built without specifying array keys like:

```
foreach ($results as $line) {
    $rows[] = array(  // <-- No array keys specified here 
        $line->name,
        $line->number,
        $line->email,
    );
}
```

Since there were no keys specified, the default by PHP is a 0-based index.  That is why you are getting no results for the top row, 1 for the second row, and so on.

See [the documentation for the `tableselect` element](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#tableselect) for an example.

I don't know what your database table structure looks like but you will probably need to query the Primary Key for the table and include it as array keys to your `$rows` array.  That way, when you process the data in your delete function, you have the Primary Key of the row you want to delete and delete it.

Comment: I did not see any changed output when I updated my code with that. What I did do was update my newsletter_table_delete_form to this:

function newsletter_table_form_delete ($form, $form_state) {
  foreach (($form_state['values']['table']) as $lines => $line) {
   if($line) {
    //$delete = db_delete('sms_newsletter')
    //-> execute();
    drupal_set_message ('' . $lines . '');
   }
  //drupal_set_message ('' . $form_state['values']['table']  . '');
  }
}

with the big difference being I changed the form_state from ['delete'] to ['table']. But now I get number responses

Comment: @LucasHealy What do you mean number responses?  what is the expected response?

Comment: First, sorry the code in that comment is so ugly. If there is a better way to do that in a comment, let me know. But basically I've gotten my module to produce a message when I select a row from the tableselect list and press delete. If I select the top row in my table I get no message back, the second row messages me 1, and so on. I'm struggling to give the full details on here without showing some code. If you are still interested, I posted my question in details here:

http://drupal.org/node/1710066

I'm basically left trying to figure out how I can identify selected rows and drop them

Comment: I suppose I didn't have an expected response, but I was hoping the response would be something that I could identify and delete the selected rows with.

Comment: @LucasHealy it's acceptable to edit your question above to provide any additional information/code pieces that aren't easily readable in comments.

Comment: Thank you, I've done that. I hope my questions are clear as your advice as been very helpful so far.

Comment: @LucasHealy Btw, for future reference... try and post only the relevant pieces of your code. I see you posted other forms and menu items that don't really apply to the problem you're describing. Minimizing your code to relevant pieces will help others troubleshoot your problem more efficiently.

Comment: Thank you so much. For the PHP help and the Stack Over Flow help :)

Answer (score 0):

For me this wasn't clear straight away so.

I would just like to add that in the end what nmc was saying is you should construct your rows like this, where you add a key to row.

```
foreach ($results as $line) {
                    $rows[$line->name] = array(
                        $line->name,
                        $line->number,
                        $line->email,
);
```